# Подписать abb файл для публикации в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

не могу разобраться уже много дней. Казалось бы, что может быть проще размещения приложения в Play Market после оплаты 25 долларов ? )

Делаю Keystore File с расширением *jks

качаю инструмент PEPK

вбиваю в консоль
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore ...

ввожу 2 пароля и получаю на выходе файл output.zip

загружаю его и получаю ответ, что он недействительный

Что делаю не так ?
Почему недействительный ? Гугл ведь еще даже моего abb файла с приложением не видели?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы продолжить используйте действительный ключ. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Гружу первое приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все блогеры в ютуб почему-то рассказывают как правильно выбрать есть реклама или нет и как вписать свой контактный адрес электронки ((

Comment: Ютуб - так себе источник знаний по программированию) В вашем случае, вроде, проблема ясна - что-то не то с датой в мета-данных ключа подписи. Посмотрите что там стоит

Comment: Там не так уж и много читаемого, касательно дат только   Not Valid Before: 2022-05-24
Not Valid After: 2072-05-11

Comment: Возможно дело в часовых поясах) Попробуйте подождать до завтра, например. Ну или пересоздать ключ, попробовав там указать вчерашнюю дату в качестве начальной (не факт, что это возможно)

Answer (score 0):

Юрий оказался прав, причина была в неверном времени (часовом поясе). Несмотря на то, что время нигде не указывается в сертификате, там только дата начала и окончания. Где-то в этом файле хранится информация о времени. Будьте внимательны !